# Remove individual ManyToManyRelationship instances through a Django view

Tags: django, django-views

So I have this `Assignment` model:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
    has_applied = models.ManyToManyField('driver.Driver', blank=True, verbose_name=_(
        "Driver applications"), related_name="driver_applications")
```

Which features a `has_applied` field with a ManyToMany relationship to the `Driver` model. I want the front-end user to be able to remove these relationships.

I have a normal DetailView from the Assignment model and use it to display a list of candidates per `Assignment` instance:

```
class AssignmentCandidateDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Assignment
    context_object_name = 'assignment_candidate_detail'
    template_name = 'pages/candidate/c.html'
```

With this url:

```
path('assignment/<int:pk>/candidates', views.AssignmentCandidateDetailView.as_view(), name='assignment-candidate-detail'),
```

And in the template I use this to get a list of the candidates that have applied and their information:

```
{% for entry in assignment_candidate_detail.has_applied.all %}
..... stuff
{% endfor %}
```

In the template list of candidates I would like to add a "Delete" button per candidate. This button will remove the ManyToMany field relationship of that particular candidate. But I am not sure how to approach this. Can someone help?

I supposse it should be something like (pseudo code):

```
def assignment_candidate_delete(request, pk):
    assignment = get_object_or_404(Assignment, pk=pk)
    assignment.has_applied.remove(candidate)
```

But how can I pass the correct information so that it removes only the relationship of a particular candidate?

**EDIT:**

So based on the anwser of I tried this:

URL:

```
path('assignment/<int:pk>/candidates/delete/<int:id>', views.assignment_candidate_delete, name='assignment-candidate-delete'),
```

Views:

```
def assignment_candidate_delete(request, pk, id):
    assignment = get_object_or_404(Assignment, pk=pk)
    assignment.has_applied.remove(id)
```

Template:

```
{% for entry in candidates %}
    <a href="{% url 'assignment-candidate-delete' request.resolver_match.kwargs.pk entry.id %}">Delete</a>
{% endfor %}
```

For me this seems to be a very ugly and hacky way to get the pk of the current page. Is there another way to get the desired pk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the body of your `DELETE` request, you should have something like

```
{
    "candidate_id": "<<<<ID>>>"
}
```

and inside your view

```
def assignment_candidate_delete(request, pk, id):
    assignment = get_object_or_404(Assignment, pk=pk)
    candidate = get_object_or_404(Driver, pk=id)
    # Check for permissions if user is authorized to do such operation.
    assignment.has_applied.filter(has_applied_id=id).delete()
    # I am not sure if 'has_applied_id' is the correct field name for the driver's
    # id on the join table, if not just use the equivalent one.
```

**Answer Update:**

for the template url generation

```
{% url 'assignment-candidate-delete' pk="<<<ASSIGNMENT_PK>>>>>" id="<<<<Driver ID>>>>" %}
# Just replace these with the respective data needed.
```

Comment: For this I need JavaScript right, to pass these in a form? Is it not possible to generate a Delete url which accepts 2 ID's. (One pk for the Assignment model and one PK for the candidate). And then just redirect to the same page?

Comment: Something like: `path('assignment/<int:pk>/candidates/delete/<int:candidate_id>', views.assignment_candidate_delete, name='assignment-candidate-delete'),`

Comment: that can work too, if you want to put the `candidate_id` as a path variable, forget about the `driver_id = request.DELETE.get('candidate_id', None)`, and just pass it with the view function parameter `def assignment_cadidate_delete(request, pk, cadidate_id), and use it inside.

Comment: If you want to put the id inside of the body, yes.
It requires doing it with javascript to pass the data,
and after the operation is done, just redirect to the same page.

Comment: Ah cool. How would I construct the URL in the template then, to accept two id's? Something like `{% url 'assignment-candidate-delete' candidate_id=entry.id %}` ?

Comment: for that you need to use the url reverse utility in django [Check This Guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-url)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206650/discussion-between-radwan-abu-odeh-and-raf-rasenberg).

Comment: The chat is crashing :/

Comment: Let me post it, I managed to get it to work thanks to your help. But I still have a question